# Why I am getting null instead of a Response from Fastapi?

Tags: python, null, fastapi

May I know where am I going wrong in fastapi

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, Response
import json
import uvicorn
app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
async def root():
    Response(content=json.dumps({"message": "hi"}), status_code=200, media_type='application/json')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, host="0.0.0.0", port=8080)
```

**I am getting null as output**

Comment: Missed the `return`?

Comment: `None`, not "null", and yes, that's what gets returned in the absence of a `return` statement.